# how to associate a child resource with a parent resource use Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a problem and need your help. If you can help me, thank you very much

```
public class A
{
    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Guid BId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid AId { get; set; }
    public A A{ get; set; }
}
```

As you see, A is the parent resource of B。

Now, I upload resource B first and then resource A。

```
// Example

// first 
BId Name AId
xxx BBB  null

// secondly
AId Name
yyy AAA
```

When I uploaded resource B, resource A was not created. After that, how can I to  use Entity Framework Core and to associate them。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I uploaded resource B, resource A was not created. After that,
> how can I to use Entity Framework Core and to associate them。

If you want to add the B data first without assigning the field AId, please **set the AId in class B to allow null**.

```
 public Guid? AId { get; set; }
```

First, add `B` to database as follow:

```
        B datab = new B()
        {
            BId = new Guid("0aa45a56-718e-44db-b5e0-894214772307"),
            Name = "bName1"
        };
        _context.B.Add(datab);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

After this, table B data is shown below:

[image]

When you create an A object, you have been able to get the data of the corresponding B object, then you only need to **assign the datab of B object to the B field of the A object to add their relationship**.

Then add A to database as follow：

```
    A dataa = new A() 
    { 
        AId = new Guid("31d23cb1-1a30-472f-8637-671f242c7438"), 
        Name = "aName1" 
    };
    dataa.B = datab; // this is the key to add AId value to B table
    _context.A.Add(dataa); 
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

After excuting this code, here is the data of table A:

[image]

Then refresh table B, here is the newest data of it:

[image]